# Extract information from a column

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have the below information from a temp table where one of the columns (i think formatted as json) is having the below information I'm trying to extract the information from that column such as path, brand, color, or activity_group on different columns. split this information.

```
    {
  "fragment": null,
  "host": null,
  "parameters": null,
  "path": "\"Fashion\",\"activity_group\":\"Fleece - Hoods / Pants\",\"brand\":\"MICHAEL Michael Kors\",\"budget_curve\":\"Crew Sweaters\",\"category\":\"Clothing\",\"category_id\":\"Clothing\",\"color\":\"Pearl Hethr 036\",\"image_url\":\"https://images.sportsdirect.com/images/products/66003602_l.jpg\",\"is_full_price\":true,\"name\":\"Logo Tape Sweatshirt\",\"price\":58,\"price_excl\":48.33,\"price_excl_gbp\":48.33,\"price_gbp\":58,\"product_discount\":0,\"product_discount_gbp\":0,\"product_id\":\"660036\",\"quantity\":1,\"sku\":\"66003602390\",\"sub_category\":\"Crew Sweaters\",\"subtotal\":48.33,\"subtotal_gbp\":48.33,\"tax\":9.67,\"tax_gbp\":9.67,\"total\":58,\"total_gbp\":58,\"variant\":\"12 (M)\"},{\"activity\":\"Fashion\",\"activity_group\":\"Leggings\",\"brand\":\"MICHAEL Michael Kors\",\"budget_curve\":\"Leggings\",\"category\":\"Clothing\",\"category_id\":\"Clothing\",\"color\":\"Pearl Hthr 036\",\"image_url\":\"https://images.sportsdirect.com/images/products/67601302_l.jpg\",\"is_full_price\":false,\"name\":\"Logo Tape Leggings\",\"price\":50,\"price_excl\":41.67,\"price_excl_gbp\":41.67,\"price_gbp\":50,\"product_discount\":35,\"product_discount_gbp\":35,\"product_id\":\"676013\",\"quantity\":1,\"sku\":\"67601302390\",\"sub_category\":\"Leggings\",\"subtotal\":41.67,\"subtotal_gbp\":41.67,\"tax\":8.33,\"tax_gbp\":8.33,\"total\":50,\"total_gbp\":50,\"variant\":\"12 (M)\"}]",
  "port": null,
  "query": null,
  "scheme": "[{\"activity\""
}
```

I tried to use parse_url and parse_json however I am not sure I am using this correctly, can someone advise what code instead parse I can use?
table name: order_dupe_check_cleaned
column name: PRODUCTS_NEED_CHECK

Comment: Could you better format your questions and correct misspellings?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a JSON string. Use json python library to extract the information from the column.

```
import json

data = '{"fragment": null, "host": null, "parameters": null, "path": "", "Fashion","activity_group":"Fleece - Hoods / Pants","brand":"The North Face","budget_curve":"Full Zip Fleece Tops","category":"Clothing","category_id":"Clothing","color":"JK3 Black","image_url":"https://images.sportsdirect.com/images/products/55435003_l.jpg","is_full_price":true,"name":"Men’s 100 Glacier Full-Zip "scheme": "[{"activity"}'

try:
    data_dict = json.loads(data)
    brand = data_dict['brand']
    color = data_dict['color']
    activity_group = data_dict['activity_group']
    print(brand)
    print(color)
    print(activity_group)
except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError as e:
    print("There is an error in the JSON string: ", e)
```

This will print the brand, color, and activity_group values. You can then store the data in separate columns.

Comment: Thanks for your response but I'm still unable to get the information I need, I'm starting as an analyst and still a bit lost, the table I'm referring to is part of a temp tab: order_dupe_check_cleaned  and the column is PRODUCTS_NEED_CHECK. Basically, I have been asked to extract the information from that column into new columns and crosscheck that with another table in a different database.